# Radial expectation value for particle in a cubic box

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

> A hydrogen atom is in a cubic box with side lengths equal to $\require{mediawiki-texvc}\pu{100 \AA{}}$. For what value of $n$ (principal quantum number) will the expectation value of the radius be equal to one-half the box size?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. Please have a look at our [Homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange/142#142).

Answer (score 3):

\[
\left< r_{nl} \right> = n^2\cdot a_0\ \left\{ 1+ \frac{1}{2} \left[1-\frac{l(l+1)}{n^2}\right] \right\}
\]

should be close to what is applicable to solve to problem in a simple way. If the value is a bit off, blame it on *Niels Bohr* or the cabinetmaker who built the box.